# AfterNavigationObserver and NavigationTrigger

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I try get NavigationTrigger type in code after click Back/Forvaward in browser

```java
@Override
public void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent event) {
    final var trigger = event.getLocationChangeEvent().getTrigger(); 
    ...
}
```

Expect get NavigationTrigger.HISTORY, but receive NavigationTrigger.CLIENT_SIDE.
Where am I wrong?

Vaadin 23.3.12

Comment: If the user has clicked in the history, then CLIENT_SIDE is what to expect. There is no way to see which history button (if any) has clicked, or perhaps he has used some bookmarks

Comment: @AndréSchild How is this related with with [https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12770](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/12770) ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but as you can see in ticket it was fixed for 24.1.x release. And since you use 23.x it's not surprising it will not work as you expect it